# rsync copy file even if file datetime is the same

Tags: rsync

I have a file /home/my/some/filename.xx with always the same datetime stamp (even if it is has been modified) with the same filesize. How could I specify to rsync that only this specific file should be copied each time? My current backup command is this:

```
sudo rsync -axvq --exclude /home/my/it/ --exclude /oit -e "ssh -i /home/my/.ssh/id_rsa" --rsync-path="sudo rsync" / user@192.168.1.1:/backup
```

Comment: Does this help ? `-c, --checksum              skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size`. I don't understand the word "only" in your sentence.

Comment: Thanks. By "only" I meant, that this rsync command should backup whole HDD to second location but all other files should be "synced" (I meant transfered just if they changed) and just this specific file "/home/my/some/filename.xx" must be transfered every time, regardless it's content has been modified or not.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Maybe a second `rsync` for just this file ...

Comment: yes, that was my second idea :) to use second rsync just for that one file and forcibly request file transfer of this file everyday.

Comment: To do that, you would `rsync` everything first, then `scp` just that one file.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to tell rsync to apply different treatment to different files based on their name is via filters. Filters can determine whether a file is synchronized at all, or whether a file is deleted, but they can't determine the method used to check whether a file is up-to-date.

So you'll have to use two separate rsync commands: one that excludes this file and one for this file specifically with a different file comparison method.

```
rsync -axvq --exclude /home/my/some/filename.xx … / user@192.168.1.1:/backup &&
rsync -axvq --checksum --include / --include /filename.xx --exclude '*' /home/my/some/ user@192.168.1.1:/backup/home/my/some/
```

In the second command, I synchronize the directory but exclude every file in it except for the file to transfer. The reason I do that is to copy the directory's timestamp, which would otherwise be modified if `filename.xx` is created. If this edge case doesn't bother you, you can simplify the second line to just copy `filename.xx`.